# How to delete file automatically older than 3 months

Tags: iphone

How to delete file automatically older than 3 months.
I am read pdf file from webservice in UIWebview and store all file in cache directory 
and again i came same view its download pdf file its ok 
I storing file in cache directory 
but i want delete particular file automatically delete in given time.How do this

Comment: @HotLicks - snarky comments are not helpful.

Comment: i can't understand why i got negative point but thanks its ok

Answer (score 1):

first make sure that when you create a new file you set a date property to the file.

then you make a method that look at all files in a directory and compare their date to now and delete those who are too old. and you call this method when the app has launched or has return to foreground.